# Why is target event referring to parent element when the child element is the element that is being hovered

Tags: javascript, html, css

Upon hovering of a child div, I am attempting to prevent event propagation such that the parent propagation will not be triggered however I am experiencing several issues where the parent `onMouseEnter` event is being triggered **BEFORE** the child despite the fact that the element being hovered is the **child element**.

The event target as identified by `(($this))` is also printing the details of the outer `<div id="kingOuter">` instead of `<div id = "kingMiddle">`

***Result***

[image]

***Code***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function () {
        var outerElement = document.createElement("div");
        outerElement.id = "kingOuter";
        outerElement.textContent = "King Outer";
        var middleElement = document.createElement("div");
        middleElement.id = "kingMiddle";
        middleElement.textContent = "King Middle";
        outerElement.onmouseenter = function(e){
            console.log($(this));
            console.log("King outer mouse enter");
        }
        middleElement.onmouseenter = function(e){
            console.log("King middle mouse enter");
        }
        let ppp = document.getElementById('tttest');
        outerElement.appendChild(middleElement);
        ppp.appendChild(outerElement);
    });
})
```

Comment: not your issue, but `$(document).ready(function() { $(function () { ...` is basically `$(document).ready(function() { $(document).ready(function() {  ...` or 
`$(function () { $(function () { ...` - i.e. it's redundant to wait for document ready inside a wait for document ready

Comment: Without seeing a runnable example it is difficult to guess - but my guess is that the child is visually within the parent so you can't get to it without hovering the parent first.

Comment: You are nesting the `middleElement` (at least, I assume that's what you mean by the 'child') INSIDE the `outerElement`. That means `outerElement` will receive the hover event before the child, regardless. If you stop propagation, it will never even reach the `middleElement`.
You're probably best off creating two sibling elements, and using `absolute` positioning to have them overlap.